# Async querying SQL in IIS

Tags: sql, f#

```
let reply =  ref ""

let doAuto  =  
    async {
        let! resultAA =
            async { return SqlCmd.aaHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultBB =
            async { return SqlCmd.bbHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultCC =
            async { return SqlCmd.ccHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultDD =
            async { return SqlCmd.ddHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultEE =
            async { return SqlCmd.ddHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultFF =
            async { return SqlCmd.ffHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultGG =
            async { return SqlCmd.ggHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultHH =
            async { return SqlCmd.hhHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultII =
            async { return SqlCmd.iiHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultJJ =
            async { return SqlCmd.jjHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }
        let! resultKK =
            async { return SqlCmd.kkHits query |> Async.RunSynchronously |> List.ofSeq }

        let length1 = resultAA.Length + resultBB.Length

        if length1 > 9 then reply := "hey " + length1.ToString()
        else
            let x = resultCC.Length + resultDD.Length + resultEE.Length + resultFF.Length + resultGG.Length 
                        + resultHH.Length + resultII.Length + resultJJ.Length + resultKK.Length + length1
            reply := x.ToString()

    } |> Async.StartImmediate

!reply
```

The typical `SqlCmd.xxHits` (in module `SqlCmd`) built using `FSharp.Data.SqlCommandTypeProvider` looks like this:

```
[<Literal>]
let sqlXX = "SELECT ...@startsWith..."

type QueryXX = SqlCommand<sqlXX, ConnectionStringName=...>

let xxHits query = 
    let cmdXxHits = QueryXX(connectionString = connectionString, startsWith = query)
    cmdXxHits.AsyncExecute()
```

I'm pretty inexperienced at using async. Looking for feedback, especially in a couple of areas:

1. I couldn't think of a better way to get my results out from inside the outer async than the ref. From what I read it sounded like `Async.StartImmediate` was the best solution for something running in an IIS application.
2. From the results of the first 2 inner asyncs, I may choose to quit before waiting for any more completions. Should I really be cancelling the remaining asyncs? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `Async.RunSynchronously` until absolutely necessary. It is very inefficient by design. Looks like you need:

```
async { let! xs = SqlCmd.xxxHits query
        return List.ofSeq xs }
```

Which you should probably abstract into a function.

Once you remove the blocking (`RunSynchronously`), the `ref` use also becomes invalid - you are querying the `ref` potentially before the async changes it - race condition. Try returning it (`return`) in the main async instead.

If you really want the subqueries to execute in parallel, consider a helper combinator like `Async.Parallel` rather than starting multiple sub-computations manually.

Your function should return `Async<string>` instead of `string`. If the caller of your code wants a `string` and cannot possibly use `Async`, they'll call `Async.RunSynchronously` - make it their problem.

Concerning choosing to quit based on the result of first two asyncs, not sure what you need exactly. Cancellation is an optimization - it may be tricky to get right but may make the code better performing. It's your decision based on the problem domain whether it is worth it or not.

Comment: Yes I want to execute in parallel, but I want to evaluate the first 2 as soon as they are ready, at which point either quit or await the remaining queries. Maybe this is too impractical and I should just execute all in parallel. Another issue I have with Async.Parallel is telling results apart.

Comment: You can execute the first 2 in parallel, and then the rest in parallel, with these two steps sequential. You might want some helper combinators like this: https://gist.github.com/toyvo/20f10e29b09688a08138

Answer (score 1):

You're running all the Asyncs through Async.RunSynchronously, which means you shouldn't be running them Async at all. You should be using Execute instead of AsyncExecute in xxHits, and all those `Async.RunSynchronously` disappear. The `let!` means that you're still waiting for each before going to the next, even if you are inside of an async. `let!` in this context just means wait for this async before continuing with the rest of this computation.

The ref lets you (try to) read the result before it is done. It should be replaced with a return. return means that the 'T in your Async<'T> is your result, and you can not get at it before it is done. One less source of bugs.

Given xxHits is:

```
let xxHits query = 
    let cmdXxHits = QueryXX(connectionString = connectionString, startsWith = query)
    cmdXxHits.Execute()
```

your main body becomes something like

```
let doAuto  =  
    let! resultAA = SqlCmd.aaHits query |> List.ofSeq
    let! resultBB = SqlCmd.bbHits query |> List.ofSeq
    ...        

    let length1 = resultAA.Length + resultBB.Length

    if length1 > 9 then reply := "hey " + length1.ToString()
    else
        let x = resultCC.Length + resultDD.Length + resultEE.Length + resultFF.Length + resultGG.Length 
                    + resultHH.Length + resultII.Length + resultJJ.Length + resultKK.Length + length1
        x.ToString()
```

As it is, you have a perf hit for running async computations that are not async.

Comment: I simplified the queries, the real ones each return something quite different. I'm trying do them in parallel (but I think Async.Parallel will not work for me) and evaluate the first 2 as soon as they are available.